# Why is it OK but not KO when username and password are incorrect?

Tags: scala, gatling

I am new user of gatling, I want to test the login scenario for one web application. I meet below issue, I write the scala script with an wrong password to test the login scenario, but I find the final result is not what I expected failure, what is the problem happened?

my scala program:

```
package cnblogsCase
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class MueasSimulation extends Simulation{
  val httpConf = http.baseURL("http://localhost:8080")
  var scn = scenario("Search mueas home page")
          .exec(http("Redirect Login").get("/").check(currentLocation.saveAs("post_url")))
          .pause(10 seconds)
          .exec(http("Try login").post("${post_url}")
              .formParam("username", "shihuc")
              .formParam("password", "123456").check(status.is(200)))
          .pause(10 seconds)
  setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(2)).protocols(httpConf))
}
```

And, the form part of login in my web application is like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/login">  
        <input type="text" required="required" name="username" placeholder="ID or Email-address">
        <input type="password" required="required" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <div class="remfog">
            <div class="rem">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" value="true" style="margin-top:10px">
                    Remember Me
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="fog">
                <a title="Reset password" href="/password/forgot">Forgot Password?</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input class="csubmit" type="submit" value="Log in">    
    </form>
```

My expected result is failed, because the username and password are incorrect in the scala script, but actually, it is OK, not KO. please check the [log](https://github.com/shihuc/First/blob/master/logs) file. My gatling version is 2.1.7.

Comment: Can you actually confirm that the webapp you are testing returns something other than "200 OK" when incorrect credentials are supplied? Not every webapp is RESTful everywhere...

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Here, I am sure my web APP is RESTful.

Answer (score 1):

As [explained in the doc](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/http/http_check.html#http-status), Gatling automatically adds a check on the HTTP status if you don't specify one.

Checking your logs, your application replies with 302/Found and a Location redirecting back to the login page.
This behaviour is wrong. In such case, the HTTP response should use a [403/Forbidden status code](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Best solution is to fix the application.
Workaround is to add an explicit check for a possible error message in the page.

Comment: Thanks for your information. But I do not agree with you "This behaviour is wrong. In such case, the HTTP response should use a 403/Forbidden status code." My web app is based on spring-boot + spring-security, the spring-security will check the username and password, if not correct, then it will redirect the http request to the login page, it will not give response with 403.

Comment: @shihuc That doesn't mean spring-security/how you use it is right. It's definitively not RESTful. Anyway, you have your answer: just relying on the HTTP status doesn't suffice in regard to your application behavior, and you have to check for an error message in the body.

Comment: I checked the log of gatling, then I find the check in scala is not reasonable, I change the "status.is(200)" to "currentLocation.is(<What URL I expected>)", then the result is what I expected KO.